# What does 'bead' mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> Their hopes rose about an hour later when they spied a helicopter approaching from the south, on a bead right toward them.

What does 'bead' mean in this sentence?

Please select from OED (https://www.evernote.com/shard/s33/sh/4dee9f72-78cf-48a9-8ae7-840b178a21bb/4300cf88d706db75f4420ba58640e0c8).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has to do with an idiom relating to aiming a gun or other weapon

> *draw (or get) a bead on*
>
> (chiefly North American) Take aim at.

*[Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/bead#bead)*

It appears to derive from

> "small knob forming front sight of a gun" 1831 (Kentucky slang); hence draw a bead on "take aim at," 1841, U.S. colloquial.

*[etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=bead)*

[image]

Comment: Oh, is that where it comes from? I always imagined a string of beads being drawn taut to provide an aiming line or something like that. Never knew that little thingy on guns was called a bead.

Comment: @philsweet Good addition. We rarely use images in ELU, but this is where it really helps.